# wxWidget, regular expression, wxRegEx, check float number

Tags: regex, wxwidgets

Please help me with the regular expression itself. I am learning it. I don't need replacement code.

I am working on wxWidget 2.8.12 with VS2008 (C++). I'd like to check whether TEST_STRING is float number. (`-0.1`, `0.1`, `1` etc.). I think the expression itself is correct, I checked by tools. Do I make mistake with wxWidget?

```
wxString tmpStr = TEST_STRING;
wxRegEx reNegativeFloatNum(_("^[-]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$"));
bool tmp = reNegativeFloatNum.Compile(tmpStr);
     tmp = tmp && reNegativeFloatNum.IsValid();
if ( tmp && reNegativeFloatNum.Matches(tmpStr))
{
    //Do something
}
else
{
    //Do something else
}
```

My real question is why the regular expression doesn't work? If I input 'a'-'Z', the Matches() return 'true'. Any one know? I just want to learn the regular expression.

Comment: Your regex says it can be negative or positive(the question mark after [-]) but the text and topic says only negative. which is it?

Comment: You are writing about negative float numbers, but in your example appear both types of numbers - positive and negative numbers. Your regular expression also matches positive and negative numbers.

Comment: If user doesn't input '-', I will add '-' automatically for him.

Comment: My real question is why the regular expression doesn't work? If I input 'a'-'Z', the Matches() return 'true'. Any one know? I just want to learn the regular expression. thanks.

Comment: Albert, you are being downvoted because a) your question has nothing to do with wxWidgets, although you have tagged it with wxWidgets. b) There many books and online tutorials about regular expressions, none of which you seem to have take the trouble to read.  It may seem mean, but people here expect you to tag your questions accurately and do some basic research before you ask a question.  If you fix your tagging and show some sign of having tried to find an answer to your question, then people will be happy to help you.

Comment: Hi, Ravenspoint, I checked my expression by tool [link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html). I don't know why the wxRegEx::Matches always return true. If the expression was wrong, why Compile() and IsValid() are passed. So I think it wx related.

Comment: The expression is valid.  It does not give the results you expect for the reasons described by dutt and Eugene

Comment: ravenspoint, Really thanks for your reply. dutt said about [-]. I am sorry for I pasted less context. So I edited post to explain. Anyway, my expression should never accept a letter, right? but when I input a letter, such as 'A', it still match(return true). I really lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP really wants to use regexes, I looked at it in details and the original regex works just fine to me. Notice that you don't need to use `_()` around regex string as this is not something you'd ever need to translate (`_` is a short synonym for `wxTRANSLATE()`) and that `Compile()` is already called by the ctor. So here is a shorter version:

```
#include <wx/init.h>
#include <wx/regex.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    wxInitializer init;
    if ( !init.IsOk() ) {
        puts("Failed to initialize wxWidgets.");
        return 1;
    }

    wxRegEx re("^[-]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$");
    return re.Matches(argv[1]);
}
```

And it works as expected:

```
    % ./a.out 123 || echo matches
    matches
    % ./a.out a-Z || echo matches
    <<<nothing>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. with your help, I fixed my fault was I misused method wxRegEx::Compile(). <br> Since I use VC++, I have to use _("") or wxT(""), otherwise I'll get a compile error.

Comment: _() and wxT() are *not* the same, please read the manual to understand the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use regular expressions for this task.  Convert the number and test it to find out if it converted to a negative number, or not.

```
if ( atof( tmpStr.c_str() < 0 ) { 
  // negative number
} else {
  // positive or not a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As ravenspoint wrote, you really don't need regular expressions for something like this (although you can use them too, of course, if you really want to, for some reason).

In wxWidgets the simplest way to do what you want is

```
double num;
if ( tmpStr.ToDouble(&num) ) {
    if ( num < 0 )
        ...
}
//else: it's not a number at all
```

Answer (score 0):

Both two methods are work: 
method 1:

```
wxRegEx re;
bool tmp = re.Compile(wxT("^[-]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$"));
if ( tmp && re.Matches(StrToBeTested))
{
    //Do sth.
}
```

method 2:

```
wxRegEx re(wxT("^[-]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+$"));
if (re.Matches(StrToBeTested))
{
    //Do sth.
}
```

According to VZ's answer, there is no need to compile again in method 2. it does work.
I just made a stupid mistake with wxRegEx::Compile's parameter. Thanks for all replies.